# Update value in class

Tags: python, class

I'm trying to do solve a Challenge which is name 'Fraction Class' I have to update a value in class but it doesn't work. Can someone please explain me why?
As you can see there are 3 function which are 'Parametrized_Constructor,add and multiply' I was trying to do when program start and then first self.Constructur do its job, i wanna update self.Constructur value to self.add or self.mult. I tried to add into add and mult function this code line 'self.Constructur = self.add and self.Constructur = self.mult' but this is not work for me.

```
class Fraction1:

def __init__(self,first_Fraction_numerator,first_Fraction_denominator,numerator,denominator):
    self.first_Fraction_numerator = first_Fraction_numerator
    self.first_Fraction_denominator = first_Fraction_denominator
    self.numerator = numerator
    self.denominator = denominator
    Fraction1.Parametrized_Constructor(self)


def Parametrized_Constructor(self):
    self.Constructur = Fraction(self.first_Fraction_numerator,self.first_Fraction_denominator)
    self.Constructur2 = Fraction(self.numerator,self.denominator)
def Add(self):
    self.add = self.Constructur + self.Constructur2
    self.Constructur = self.add

    print(self.add)

def Multiply(self):
    self.mult = self.Constructur * self.Constructur2
    self.Constructur = self.mult
    print(self.mult)


first_Fraction_numerator, first_Fraction_denominator = map(int,input().split())
numberofarray = int(input())

while numberofarray:
    for i in range(numberofarray):
        choice,numerator,denominator = map(int,input().split())
        if choice == 1:
            a = Fraction1(first_Fraction_numerator,first_Fraction_denominator,numerator,denominator)
            a.Add()
            numberofarray-=1
        elif choice ==2:
            a = Fraction1(first_Fraction_numerator,first_Fraction_denominator,numerator,denominator)
            a.Multiply()
            numberofarray-=1
```

Comment: Mmmm, could you share the full error message you get? "It doesn't work" is a poor way of describing an error. Also, it would be nice to include a piece of code we can actually run to test it. Copy-paste your own code and try running it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. What's the problem exactly? "It's not working" is not descriptive enough. Like, is it throwing an error, or is the output incorrect? And this code is not properly indented. You need to make a [mre]. You can [edit] your post, and please write a more descriptive title when you do.

Comment: I don't get any. Let me explain. My simple input is like this:

First line represent first  numerator and denominator. 
second line represent how much value we give which is also consist of operation number,num and den.
 
47 71
3
1 91 78
2 67 75
1 36 74

At first the Parametrized_Constructor function is called and prints the first value and the second value as Fraction. Then we send these values ​​to the process according to the choice number. If choice = 1, add, if choice = 2, multiply. When he goes to Choice 1, he trades 47/71 + 91/78 = 779/426.

Comment: After this point, I want to replace the Constructor value (47/71) with 779/426. Then the second part comes and is processed with 779/426 according to the transaction number.

Answer (score 0):

If your working with numbers and not booleans try this:

```py
self.Constructur = self.add + self.Constructur
self.mult = self.Constructur
```

Comment: That's not what i want :/

Comment: @AbdullahKılınç, Do you want constructor to be either `self.add` or `self.mult`? Where do you want your result

Comment: Could be possible, maybe

Comment: @AbdullahKılınç From your OP, is something like you are looking for `self.add += self. self.add + self.mult` with the next line being `self.constructor = self.add`?

Comment: Let me explain to you about what i want: 

My simple input is like this: First line represent first numerator and denominator. second line represent how much value we give which is also consist of operation number,num and den. 47 71 3 1 91 78 2 67 75 1 36 74 At first the Parametrized_Constructor function is called and prints the first value and the second value as Fraction. Then we send these values ​​to the process according to the choice number. If choice = 1, add, if choice = 2, multiply. When he goes to Choice 1, he trades 47/71 + 91/78 = 779/426.

Comment: After this point, I want to replace the Constructor value (47/71) with 779/426. Then the second part comes and is processed with 779/426 according to the transaction number.

Comment: But it's hard to undestand if you want i can send you link of challenge?

Comment: @AbdullahKılınç Yes, that would help.

Comment: https://www.codingninjas.com/codestudio/guided-paths/basics-of-python/content/118797/offering/1467362

Comment: @AbdullahKılınç, You have no function named `Fraction`. When I ran this is got `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 41, in <module>
    a = Fraction1(first_Fraction_numerator, first_Fraction_denominator,
  File "main.py", line 8, in __init__
    Fraction1.Parametrized_Constructor(self)
  File "main.py", line 11, in Parametrized_Constructor
    self.Constructur = Fraction(self.first_Fraction_numerator,
NameError: name 'Fraction' is not defined`. Could this be the stem of your problems?